# Markov chains: is "aperiodic + irreducible" equivalent to "regular"?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have two books on stochastic processes.

In one book, it says that the limiting matrix is possible to find if the matrix is regular, that is, if for some $n$ $P^n$ has only positive values.  The other book says that the limiting values are possible to find if the Markov chain is recurrent, irreducible and aperiodic; it is then called ergodic.

Does this then hold:

**aperiodic + irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$ ergodic $\Leftrightarrow$ regular**?

And is there any difference whether it is a finite-state chain or not?

Comment: Is late now I guess but it woud be great to have the name of the books

Answer (score 18):

For a finite MC it holds that

**aperiodic + irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$ ergodic $\Leftrightarrow$ regular**

as you expected. For an infinite MC it holds that

**aperiodic + irreducible + positive recurrent $\Leftrightarrow$ ergodic**,

and being "regular" in the infinite setting would require a more precise definition.

*................................ explanations following ................................*

For every finite or inifinite Markov chain (MC) it holds that

$aperiodic + irreducible + positive~recurrent \Leftrightarrow ergodic$.

See for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122688/how-to-prove-ergodic-property-from-aperiodicity-and-positive-recurrence) for a proof. For every *finite* MC, irreducibility already *implies* positive recurrence, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297278/irreducible-finite-markov-chains-are-positive-recurrent) for a proof.

Further, for every finite MC we have that

$aperiodic + irreducible \Leftrightarrow regular$.

*Proof sketch*: the definition of a finite irreducible MC gives that $\forall i, j \in \Omega : \exists k > 0 : P^k[i,j] > 0$.
However, there might be no $k$ such that all entries are simultaneously positive - due to periodicities. But if the chain is additionally aperiodic, it follows that
$\exists k > 0 : \forall i, j \in \Omega : P^k[i,j] > 0$,
which matches your definition of being regular.

Finally, I don't see a canonical way how you would generalize the property "regular" to infinite Markov chains. So, I just ignore the term "regular" for infinite chains here.

Comment: Thank you very much!, it cleared the situation up for me!

Comment: Are you sure that the "+⇔" part is correct? What raises my concerns, is the following sentence on p.598 in Murphy, Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective, 2012: *"One can show that **sufficient conditions** to ensure regularity are that the chain be irreducible (singly connected) and that every state have a self-transition."* The self-transition implies aperiodicity, but the condition is entitled as only sufficient, but not necessary.

Comment: It is not necessary to have self-transitions, that's probably what the book means.

Comment: Regarding the last point, my first guess would be to explore countably infinite Markov processes as a limit of finite Markov processes, each of which is regular?