# Why are all finite state Markov Chains positive recurrent?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

This makes sense to me intuitively, since infinite return time if null recurrent (or transient i.e positive probability of no return) doesn't seem to be possible if there are *finite* states.

I found a convincing argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297278/irreducible-finite-markov-chains-are-positive-recurrent), but I'm not able to prove this mathematically. Could someone please provide hints/outline for a proof?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

for an algebraic proof, note that if your chain had no positive recurrent class then that means it decomposes purely into null recurrent and transient classes.

This implies  $P^k\to \mathbf 0$
using the Frobenius norm for convenience, this is equivalent to
$\big\Vert P^k-\mathbf 0\big \Vert_F \lt \epsilon$
for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ for $k$ large enough.

but $P\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$ so $\lambda_1=1$ is an eigenvalue of $P$.  Applying Schur Triangularization to $P$ we get
$1 =\lambda_1^k \leq \big\Vert P^k-\mathbf 0\big \Vert_F $
for all $k$ so $P^k\to \mathbf 0$ is impossible and $P$ must contain a positive recurrent class.

*wordsmithing note to OP*: it isn't actually true that all finite state markov chains 'are' positive recurrent, it is true that they must contain a positive recurrent class.  (To falsify the former, e.g. construct a simple absorbing state chain where absorbtion happens WP1.) Alternatively you could say that all *irreducible* finite state markov chains are positive recurrent.