# Prove all states are persistent

Tags: probability, markov-chains, transition-matrix

Suppose we have a time-homogeneous chain with a state space with $d$ states, where $d\in\mathbb N^+$. The transition matrix $P$ is given as below, which is a $d\times d$ matrix.

$ P=  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0  & 0 & 0\\
    \frac{1}{4d} & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{d-1}{4d} & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & \frac{2}{4d} & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{d-2}{4d} & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & \frac{d-1}{4d} & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4d}\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4}
  \end{bmatrix}$

I want to show that all states are persistent.

So, I try to calculate $f_{ij}(n)$, the probability of returning to state  for the first time, given we start in state  in  steps. But it turns out that for large $n$, $f_{ij}(n)$ becomes very complicated and contains many terms (due to the fact that we can stay at many different states during the process). I was somehow stuck here. Thanks for help on showing that all states are persistent **by direct calculation**.

---

I know a way to prove that all states are persistent, but it is not based on much calculation. Here is the reasoning: We know the chain is irreducible from $P$. It is finite-state. We are done. However, I want to prove the result by direct calculation/its definition. Thanks!

Comment: Calculation is not needed. An irreducible finite-state Markov chain is necessarily (positive) recurrent. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297278/irreducible-finite-markov-chains-are-positive-recurrent

Comment: @Math1000 I know the logical proof (which is exactly the one I mentioned in the OP) but I want a proof based on calculation and its definition. That's, I want to really "see" the property, rather than quoting various theorems/propositions. Thanks.